# Prepare custom json format return in MVC c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have two classes, namely `Roles` and `Module` in `Module` class I have two properties `Name`,`Permission`.

for now, just testing purpose I'm creating one demo code.

> Class file

```
    public class Roles
    {
        public Module[] modules { get; set; }
        public Roles()
        {
            modules = new Module[] { };
        }
    }

    public class Module
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] Permission { get; set; }
    }
```

> Controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    var oRoles = new Roles();
    oRoles.modules = new Module[] {
        new Module(){
            Name="Page-Profile",
            Permission=new string[]{ "Edit","View","Delete"}
        },
        new Module(){
            Name="User",
            Permission=new string[]{ "Edit","View","Delete","Update"}
        }
    };
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oRoles);
    return View(json);
}
```

It's working fine I'm getting result also but I want result like this.

> Expected result.

```
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "Page-Profile": [
        "Edit",
        "View",        
        "Delete"
      ]
    },
    {
      "User": [
        "Edit",
        "View",
        "Update",
        "Delete"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

> Currently I'm getting a result like this. `is there any way to modify JSON remove all key and get only values`.

```
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "Name": "Page-Profile",
      "Permission": [
        "Edit",
        "View",
        "Delete"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "User",
      "Permission": [
        "Edit",
        "View",
        "Delete",
        "Update"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** How to remove key properties i want only name value and in name `value` again i wan't all `permission` as mention in `excpected result`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Module class and try changing Roles as follows to get expected json format:

```
    public class Roles
    {
        public Roles()
        {
            modules = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> modules { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Action code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    var oRoles = new Roles();
    oRoles.modules.Add("Page-Profile", new List<string>{"Edit","View","Delete"});
    oRoles.modules.Add("user", new List<string>{"Edit","View","Delete","Update"});
    // Not sure why you are serializing to json. 
    // you can directly return View(oRoles) or PartialView(oRoles)
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oRoles);
    return View(json);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man it's work perfectly :) I must appreciate it, bro.

Comment: Although it worked for me but the output I am getting is `{
  "roles": {
    "modules": {
      "23": [
        "Edit",
        "Update"
      ],
      "26": [
        "Edit",
        "Update"
      ],
      "35": [
        "Edit",
        "Update"
      ]
    }
  }
}` but i want `module` as `array object`

Comment: @jishansiddique - check my answer which uses custom `JsonConverter`. It results the output the module as  array --- `{"modules":[{"Page-Profile":["Edit","View","Delete"]},{"User":["Edit","View","Delete","Update"]}]}`. Dotnet fiddle link - [https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hs3i04](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hs3i04)

Comment: @user1672994, yes currently I'm looking your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to achieve it

1. By writing the custom converter
2. By changing the Roles object

**By writing the custom converter**

You can implement the CustomJsonConverter as follows which convert the name to key and permission to value:

```
public class FlatternKeysConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Module o = (Module)value;
        JObject newObject = new JObject(new JProperty(o.Name, o.Permission));
        newObject.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And attach the `JsonConverter` as

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FlatternKeysConverter))]
public class Module
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Permission { get; set; }
}
```

The generated JSON will be as follows :

```
{"modules":[{"Page-Profile":["Edit","View","Delete"]},{"User":["Edit","View","Delete","Update"]}]}
```

**By changing the Roles object**

Change the roles object to dictionary

```
public class Role
{
    public class Roles
    {
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Modules {get; set;}
    }
}
```

You can check the https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hs3i04 dotnet fiddle which shows both approaches.

Comment: Is there any way without a `custom converter` to achieve it?

Comment: It's call you should take to either change the object structure or achieve it without changing the structure. The JsonConverter gives a clean approach which would not require any structure change

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me ,try this :

> Code

```
public class Roles
{
    public Roles()
    {   
        modules = new List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
    }

    public List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> modules { get; set; }
}



/*Index*/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var oRoles = new Roles();   
    var userRolePermissionsAndModulesList =  userRolePermissionManager.GetAllUserRolePermissionsAndModules(userId);

    foreach (var module in userRolePermissionsAndModulesList)
    { 
        var objPermissionWithModules = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        var permission = new List<string> { };

        if (module.CanCreate)
        permission.Add("Create");
        if (module.CanDelete)
        permission.Add("Delete");
        if (module.CanEdit)
        permission.Add("Update");
        if (module.CanView)
        permission.Add("View");

        objPermissionWithModules.Add(module.ModuleName, permission);
        oRoles.modules.Add(objPermissionWithModules);
    } 

    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oRoles);

    return View(json);
}
```

> Please compare your output :

```
{
   "modules":[
      {
         "Page-Profile":[
            "Edit",
            "View",
            "Delete"
         ]
      },
      {
         "user":[
            "Edit",
            "View",
            "Delete",
            "Update"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer how can fixed for multiple `modules`

Comment: Please review my answer I have mentioned over there.

Comment: edited my code for the same,added a foreach for multiple entries , this might work in that case,please review

Comment: Ok, I'm trying I also done the same code wait a minute I'll check and let you now.